# Javascript IFrame load event when downloading file ContentDisposition = attachment

Tags: javascript, iframe, asp.net-web-api

Im having trouble getting the IFrame load event triggered when download a file ContentDisposition = attachment.

My server side is a C# Web API:

```
var stream = Report.Common.SampleReport(ReportExportFormat.PDF, new string[] { "TEST" }, "testreport");

            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

            response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(stream);
            response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
            response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "testreport.pdf";
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType =
                new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
            return response;
```

So my `IFrame` load event is never triggered, If instead of trying to download a file I set the `src` property of my `IFrame` to `www.yahoo.com` then the load event is triggered. So is there any way to workaround this issue?

Thanks and appreciate any advice.

Comment: Did you ever find a way to fix this?